# Spacing elements in a circular array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is an interesting problem I've come across that I feel should have an elegant, provable solution but I haven't quite been able to get it. I've defined it as:

> Define a function that takes as input an array of N elements and a
>   positive integer R, and returns a circular array (or an array that you
>   treat as circular) where no two identical elements are less than R
>   apart, or a null if no such ordering is possible.

So `f([a,b,d,c,a,d,k,a,d], 3)` might return `[a,b,d,a,k,d,a,c,d]`, but `f([a,b,d,c,a,d,k,a,d,a,a], 3)` would return `null`. I define two elements as being `R apart` if they have `R-1` elements between them, so in the array `[x,a,b,y]`, `x` and `y` are 3 apart on one side and 0 apart on the other.

I feel like this would be a great interview question as well.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev- While I agree that your condition is sufficient for there to be no ordering, is it necessary?  Also, could you use your approach to produce an order when one exists?

Comment: @EvgenyKluev- I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  I don't see how sorting the array can produce a working solution when there is one, nor do I see why sorting the array and noting that there aren't too many copies of an element gives a guarantee that there is a way of arranging the elements.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @templatetypedef, I misunderstood the question. Sorry.

Comment: Fascinating question! In what context did it arise for you?

Comment: You can use this to define an even distribution of nodes given a certain replication strategy in Cassandra :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Split the array into groups of identical elements (with sorting or using a hashtable).
2. Find the largest group. If its size is greater than `floor(N/R)`, return null.
3. If size of the largest group equals exactly `N/R`, partition (partially sort) the list of groups, so that all the groups of size `N/R` come first in the following step.
4. For each group, put its elements to the result array (circular buffer), incrementing index by `R`, while it is possible. If `R` and `N` are not co-prime, sometimes - after `N/GCD(N,R)` increments - index will point to already used element. In such cases increment index by `R+1` instead of `R` and continue.

Comment: Are you sure that this works correctly?  I think you're right, but I'm not 100% convinced that this won't end up making a locally optimal decision that is globally suboptimal.

Comment: @B_. - sorry, but i don't understand your objection.  i've implemented what i understand from the above and that sequence works ok (i think?).  please see my answer here for the code.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment because it turned out I had slightly misinterpreted this answer. I'm marking it right because I can't find a counterexample (thanks andrew), though I'll try later to make a formal proof of it.

Comment: @B_. Everyone, criticizing my answer, is right. The longest group might give a problem if inserted in the middle of the array. Now it is corrected. The formal proof should be very easy because (1) elements are explicitly added `R` apart at step 4, and (2) head and tail of any group cannot be closer, than `R` because their size is controlled at step 2 and largest groups are aligned at step 3.

Comment: @templatetypedef, I think, the word 'optimal' is not right here. This is not an optimization task. This algorithm may be only correct or incorrect. And it was actually incorrect. I fixed it now.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev, thanks for continuing to update. The detail you added now is one that both I and the other answerer below implemented by choosing to place the groups in descending order of size. I'm interested in your conclusion that that can be loosened to only placing groups of size N/R first, instead of needing to do it by largest-to-smallest regardless.

Answer (score 2):

i'm sorry, i'm feeling dumb here, but i don't understand the objections to Evgeny's solution.  i think the code below implements what they suggest (except i throw an error rather than return null) and works fine with the sequence that is supposed to be problematic.

i'm posting this as an answer largely because i want to post the code for correction.  presumably it has the same problem as the earlier answer, so please can someone explain what the problem is?

(ps in my case, the groups are also ordered by length, which isn't explicitly given earlier).

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def ring(n, text):
    result = [None for t in text]
    index = 0
    for c in Counter(text).elements():
        while result[index] is not None:
            index = (index + 1) % len(result)
        result[index] = c
        index = (index + n) % len(result)
    loop = ''.join(result)
    print(text, ' -> ', loop)
    check(n, loop)

def check(n, text):
    loop = text + text
    last = defaultdict(lambda: -n)
    for (i,c) in enumerate(loop):
        assert i - last[c] >= n, (c, i - last[c])
        last[c] = i

ring(3, 'aaaabbbcccdd') # problematic according to B_?
ring(3, 'abdcadkad')    # given in question
ring(3, 'abdcadkadaa')  # given in question, expected to fail
```

and running:

```
> python3.2 ring.py 
aaaabbbcccdd  ->  acbacbacdabd
abdcadkad  ->  akdacdabd
abdcadkadaa  ->  aadakdacdab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ring.py", line 25, in <module>
    ring(3, 'abdcadkadaa')
  File "ring.py", line 14, in ring
    check(n, loop)
  File "ring.py", line 20, in check
    assert i - last[c] >= n, (c, i - last[c])
AssertionError: ('a', 1)
```

Comment: Yep, yours does give a good ordering for those examples. The difference between how I had implemented it (I'd thought of that scheme already) and yours is that for every new set of duplicate elements, I started at the "top" of the list again instead of continuing from wherever I was. I don't see exactly why your solution would work for all inputs when that solution does not, so I'll keep looking at it. Thanks!

Comment: ah, ok.  no, that wouldn't work.  but i don't have a formal proof for this either.

Comment: by construction the gap between similar letters is always the minimum required, or one more.  the only problem is when you do an entire loop, with the "one more" jump in the middle.  then you may have an issue if that jump pushes the "ends" together.  i think a proof just has to enumerate those cases.  but i am going to bed...

Answer (score 1):

I sense a wee bit of a temper there. I don't do this for points. I do it because I enjoy it. I gave you a lot and thought you would be able to carry through on your own.  Anyway, this is a place where complete strangers help complete strangers.

Here is a code, with the results of the tests following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ResolvingAlgo {

public static Character[] resolver(Character[] objects, int R) {
    //calculate frequency of each element
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (Character c : objects) {
        Integer freq = map.get(c);
        map.put(c, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
    }
    //count elements with frequency R
    List<Character> pillars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (Character c : map.keySet()) {
        int freq = map.get(c);
        if (R == freq) {
            pillars.add(c);
        } else if (objects.length/R < freq) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    //output array
    Character output[] = new Character[objects.length];
    //load the pillars R+1 apart
    int skip = (pillars.size()<R)?R:R+1;
    for (Character c : pillars) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int out=index; out<output.length; out++) {
            if (output[out] == null) {
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        for (int i = R; i > 0; i--) {
            output[index] = c;
            index += skip;
        }
        map.remove(c);
    }//pillars
    //add remainders
    while (!map.isEmpty()) {
        int index = 0;
        Character keyset[] = Arrays.copyOf(map.keySet().toArray(new Character[0]), map.size());
        for (Character c : keyset) {
            for (int out = index; out < output.length; out++) {
                if (null == output[out]) {
                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }
            output[index] = c;
            int freq = map.get(c);
            if (freq <= 1) {
                map.remove(c);
            } else {
                map.put(c, freq - 1);
            }
        }//for keyset
    }//while
    return output;
}//resolver

public static void main(String... args) {
    Character[][] input = {
        {'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'},
        {'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'k'},
        {'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'k'},
        {'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'k', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'a'},
        {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'},
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'},
        {'a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'}
    };
    for(Character in[]: input)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resolver(in, 3)));
}
}
```

Result of test:

```
[d, b, c, a, d, b, c, a, d, b, c, a]
[b, c, a, d, b, c, a, k, b, c, a, d]
[d, a, b, d, a, c, d, a, k]
null
[b, c, d, b, c, a, b, c, d, a, a, a]
[f, d, e, b, c, a, f, d, e, b, c, a]
[d, b, c, a, d, b, c, a]
```

Comment: This is a similar implementation to the one Evgeny suggested and suffers the same issues.

Comment: I read the reply you mention. It is different from mine in that it does not always reinsert the largest group first, which would be a problem in many instance. I am going to run in input set.

Comment: Thanks for the challenge. I found the bug and fixed it. R must be greater than or equal to the number of different duplicate objects. Check the code for more detail.

Comment: This is not true. The only requirement, as far as I can tell, is that no one element has more than `N/R` duplicates (as Evgeny noted). For instance, the list `[a,a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d]` with `R=3` has at least the solution `[a,b,c,a,b,d,a,b,c,a,d,c]`.

Comment: With the list I posted, for instance. With the restriction you imposed it would fail for any trivial input where there were more elements that had duplicates than R, e.g. `[a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d]` with `R=3`, for which a solution is `[a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d]`

Comment: I see that. well between me and the other person you have your answer.

Comment: Haha, no temper! I appreciate you trying to learn and help and I've read and tested all your updates :), I was just trying to help when you said something I perceived as incorrect.

Comment: Your code still produces incorrect output. For instance, for the input  `{'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'}` it returns `[b, c, d, b, c, a, b, c, d, a, a, a]` which is not valid given the constraints. I suggest you check out andrew cooke's answer for a nice implementation of the consensus so far.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This is not a solution. It's just a reformulation.

To fix notation, say there `m` different types of elements (may as well call then `1,2,...,m`) and there are `a_i` elements of type `i`. Then we have `a_1 + ... + a_m = N`.

Let `G(N,R)` be the graph with vertices `v1, v2, ..., vN` where there is an edge `vi <--> vj` whenever `|i-j| mod N < R`. For example, `G(N,2)` is the `N`-cycle. The question asks for a [proper coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring) of the `N`-cycle with `a_i` vertices colored `i`.

In this context, the question is equivalent to computing the nonzero coefficients of [Stanley's chromatic symmetric function](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/100.pdf). This may not make the problem any easier, but it certainly makes it more interesting in my mind. For example, I believe the answer is known for `G(N,2)`, something like it exists iff `max(a_i) <= N/2` (certainly no solution exists if any `a_i > N/R`). I'll update this non-answer after a bit more research.